# How to finda text and get the page no. for acrobat using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find the text and get the page number of text found in acrobat using VBA, I am able to find the text but not able to get the page number. for that

```
Sub Main()

Dim acrApp, acrAVDoc
Set acrApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.app")
Set acrAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
acrApp.Show
If acrAVDoc.Open("FileName", "") Then
    Ok = acrAVDoc.FindText("Text to search", 0, 1, 1)
    MsgBox (Ok)
End If

Set acrAVDoc = Nothing
Set acrApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I am not able to set the object for

```
Set acrPDDoc = CreateObject("Acrobat.AV_PAGE_VIEW")
```

Comment: Can you find the reference of `Acrobat.AV_PAGE_VIEW` in the references? ;).

Comment: I am able to find the reference of AV_PAGE_VIEW but not able to create object for that

Comment: As a try please check the reference, then add an object like `Dim test As ...` from the library or a class that you want instead of your current `set` code, When you have a valid statement that covers your requirements; you can change it to `set`  format, try this and add your results to your question ;).

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but it was one of the top search results when I was looking for the same info. I never found anything that truly met my needs so I made something up by combining several different resources.

The function below is acceptably fast, even on very large documents. It searches page by page, not word by word, so it will find multi-word matches and words with dashes (case insensitive). It returns the matches for all pages separated by commas.

Hope this is helpful to someone in the future.

```
Sub Demo()
Dim SearchResult As String    
SearchResult = AdobePdfSearch("my search string", "C:\Demo\Demo.pdf")
MsgBox SearchResult
End Sub
```

---

```
Function AdobePdfSearch(SearchString As String, strFileName As String) As String
'Note: A Reference to the Adobe Library must be set in Tools|References!
'Note! This only works with Acrobat Pro installed on your PC, will not work with Reader
Dim AcroApp As CAcroApp, AcroAVDoc As CAcroAVDoc, AcroPDDoc As CAcroPDDoc
Dim AcroHiliteList As CAcroHiliteList, AcroTextSelect As CAcroPDTextSelect
Dim PageNumber, PageContent, Content, i, j, iNumPages
Dim strResult As String

Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set AcroAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
If AcroAVDoc.Open(strFileName, vbNull) <> True Then Exit Function

Set AcroPDDoc = AcroAVDoc.GetPDDoc
iNumPages = AcroPDDoc.GetNumPages
For i = 0 To iNumPages - 1

    Set PageNumber = AcroPDDoc.AcquirePage(i)
    Set PageContent = CreateObject("AcroExch.HiliteList")
    If PageContent.Add(0, 9000) <> True Then Exit Function
    Set AcroTextSelect = PageNumber.CreatePageHilite(PageContent)
    ' The next line is needed to avoid errors with protected PDFs that can't be read
    On Error Resume Next
    For j = 0 To AcroTextSelect.GetNumText - 1
        Content = Content & AcroTextSelect.GetText(j)
    Next j
    If InStr(1, LCase(Content), LCase(SearchString)) > 0 Then
        strResult = IIf(strResult = "", i + 1, strResult & "," & i + 1)
    End If
    Content = ""
Next i

AdobePdfSearch = strResult

'Uncomment the lines below if you want to close the PDF when done.
'AcroAVDoc.Close True
'AcroApp.Exit
'Set AcroAVDoc = Nothing: Set AcroApp = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

sub checks each page of pdf, word by word

Sub FindtextandPageNumber()

```
    Dim FindWord        'Word you want to search
    Dim acroAppObj As Object
    Dim PDFDocObj As Object
    Dim myPDFPageHiliteObj As Object

    Dim iword As Integer, iTotalWords As Integer
    Dim numOfPage As Integer, Nthpage As Integer
    Dim word As String, sPath As String

   Set acroAppObj = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
   Set PDFDocObj = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
   Set myPDFPageHiliteObj = CreateObject("AcroExch.HiliteList")
   Check3 = myPDFPageHiliteObj.Add(0, 32767)
    FindWord = "Hello"
    acroAppObj.Show
    sPath = "Test.pdf"          'Path of pdf where you want to search
    PDFDocObj.Open (sPath)

    numOfPage = PDFDocObj.GetNumPages

    word = vbNullString
 Set PDFJScriptObj = Nothing

    For Nthpage = 0 To numOfPage - 1
      Set pAcroPDPage = PDFDocObj.AcquirePage(Nthpage)
      Set wordHilite = pAcroPDPage.CreateWordHilite(myPDFPageHiliteObj)
      Set PDFJScriptObj = PDFDocObj.GetJSObject
       iTotalWords = wordHilite.GetNumText
        iTotalWords = PDFJScriptObj.getPageNumWords(Nthpage)
        ''check the each word
        For iword = 0 To iTotalWords - 1
           word = Trim(CStr(PDFJScriptObj.getPageNthWord(Nthpage, iword)))
            If word <> "" Then
                If word = FindWord Then
                    PageNumber = Nthpage
                    msgbox PageNumber
                End If
                word = ""
            End If
        Next iword
    Next Nthpage
```

End Sub

Comment: This saved me some significant time and effort. I changed the line `If word = FindWord Then` to `If InStr(1, UCase(word), UCase(FindWord)) > 0 Then` to make it find partial matches and be case insensitive (as well making some other changes to convert it into a function). Thanks! +1

Comment: Update: This script above works, but has some flaws. It searches word by word, which means you can search for a multi word string or one containing dashes. It's also very, very slow on large documents. I'll put a more optimized script I made up in a new answer.