# Macro which search keywords in pdf and give page number

Tags: excel, vba

I want a excel macro which search words in PDF and give the page number where macro finds the words. I have 20 words that I want to search in PDF. I have put the keywords in coulmn A of the excel spreadsheet and I want to populate the page number in coulmn b. Please note that I am currently using Adobe reader XI, so please help me with the code which also work in Adobe reader XI.

Comment: Do you think vba code will work in Adobe?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a direction and not an answer.

Try searching for command line tools that will export ocr data into a text file.  I've looked at them before and a few gave me the option of looking at the particular page of a pdf.  All of these tools require a purchase (I was trying to OCR a barcode and I could not find a free tool for this) but there are some free ones out there.

But using excel will make this project harder.  I would look at using powershell or some other scripting language and exporting the results into a csv file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Below is the code which give me the page number in excel but it is only working in Adobe pro and writer. Is it possible to modify the code in such a way that it will also work in Adobe reader ?

Comment: Sorry I am not being able to paste the entire code over here. Hence, pasting the website where I have found that code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773754/how-to-finda-text-and-get-the-page-no-for-acrobat-using-vba

Comment: You might be able to get the page number but I do not know of any ocr api's that allow you to do that type of searching on a pdf.